# My /usr directory is 100% full. Unable to download packages

Tags: linux, command-line, files, disk-usage

What kinds of files are okay to delete in /usr directory without blowing up the server?? Is it possible to increase the size of /usr directory without blowing up  server?

Comment: How is your directory full?  Do you mean your mount?  Is it possible your entire drive is full?

Comment: @DarkSheep my other directories like /var , / ,/opt have enough space.

Comment: Are you using LVM? Is `/var` on a logical volume?

Comment: @Torin I am not using LVM for /var or /usr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `/usr` directory usually contains the `/usr/share/doc` directory tree which contains just documentation files. That should be fairly safe to move elsewhere or outright delete in case of emergency.

But you should use something like `du -kx /usr | sort -rn | less` to list the directories in the `/usr` filesystem in order of decreasing size, and so find out what is taking the most space. For example, here's the beginning of such a listing from my system:

```
14638572        /usr
7232184 /usr/share
6150780 /usr/lib
2195108 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
2143388 /usr/share/doc
1213312 /usr/share/doc/texlive-doc
1123212 /usr/lib/debug
816908  /usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/latex
775616  /usr/share/locale
731592  /usr/bin
589800  /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu
503216  /usr/lib/python2.7
442400  /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
324104  /usr/share/fonts
315548  /usr/include
313148  /usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/generic
301928  /usr/share/texlive
300248  /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist
292876  /usr/lib/libreoffice
...
```

Obviously `/usr`is at the top, since it contains everything else. `/usr/share` and `/usr/lib` both contain stuff that is important to various programs. However, if the use of `/usr` has suddenly grown, it might be useful to take a look inside those directories to see if there are any new files accidentally misplaced in there.

But it does look like `/usr/share/doc` takes a significant chunk of my `/usr`, and in particular, `/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc` is a major disk hog.

Based on this, I could go to package manager, and look at any `*-doc` packages, in particular any TeXLive documentation packages, and tell the package manager to uninstall them if they are not needed.

(If this was a critical server and I needed some disk space in `/usr` ASAP, I might just delete `/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc` and rely on the package manager to reinstall its contents if necessary. But I would strongly prefer using the package manager instead of just deleting entire directories manually.)

`/usr/lib/debug` is also fairly big; perhaps I've forgotten to uninstall some debugging packages I no longer need?

Answer (score 0):

If you boot with a [LiveUSB](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#0) ([Windows instructions also available](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0)) you can use [gparted](https://gparted.org/) to expand a partition IF you don't end up [moving the boot partition start point](https://askubuntu.com/questions/640497/moving-the-boot-partition). If you need further assistance, run [fdisk](https://www.howtogeek.com/106873/how-to-use-fdisk-to-manage-partitions-on-linux/), copy the screen contents, then go to your original question and click on edit to paste the results into your question so we can see more about your situation. Also happy to provide links for instructions for your version of Linux if you are not using an Ubuntu family distro.